# Minimalmodbus - RS485 shield for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, rs485, minimalmodbus

I am trying to interface  Seeed Studio's **RS485 shield for Raspberry Pi** along with the Python **Minimalmodbus** library on Raspberry Pi 2B - **NOT WORKING!!!**

shield : https://www.seeedstudio.com/RS-485-Shield-for-Raspberry-Pi.html

I tested following on Raspberry Pi:

- It worked fine if I send data using Python **serial** library. It turns on a relay on a slave device and responds correctly.

`ser.write('\xff\x05\x00\x00\xff\x00\x99\xe4')`

- It is not working if I use **Minimalmodbus** library for Python

`instrument.write_bit(0,1,5)`

**error:** minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)

**note: I used same Minimalmodbus python code using another USB-to-RS485 converter on same RPi and it worked fine.**

Pyhton Code:

```
import minimalmodbus

import time

import serial 

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyAMA0', 255)


instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600      
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout  = 1          
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU  
instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
instrument.debug = True

while 1:
    
    instrument.write_bit(0,1,5)

    time.sleep(5)
```

**error:** minimalmodbus.NoResponseError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)

Can anybody help if I can use this specific rs485-shield with Minimalmodbus library?
Thank you in advance

Regards,

Comment: Hey Mondo, Did you ever get this working? I am having the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

The `write_bit` function is reading the response after the message is sent. And Seeed RS-485 Shield needs to toggle the `GPIO18` pin to switch between reading and writing. As is shown in the sample code in documentation https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/RS-485_Shield_for_Raspberry_Pi/#communication-test-code.

By checking the code of `write_bit` function I don't think that there is an easy way to toggle that pin as between `serial.write` and `serial.read` these no place to register own hook and toggle the PIN there (https://github.com/pyhys/minimalmodbus/blob/c08208523b729d178a9f662725a69195924f7c34/minimalmodbus.py#L1379).